# How do I access data from the model via the controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know this seems like an easy question but I believe the viewbag is what gives me access to the data from a model but I want to access the model class directly and not create an instance of it. I know that you can do that with the main index method by using the model class as a parameter but how do I do the same thing with a method that I create?

Here is my code below and I'm trying to figure out how to pass the model class as a parameter so the method that I'm calling can access all of the information:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // if user changes paper type
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getNewPrice","Home")',
            data: {dropdownValue:value, dropdownName: "paperType"},
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you show your method and your model?

Comment: I just posted the code

Comment: You could update your question, you just put the update `Edit` as an answer. And if I understand you want to use a method with your model. But don't want to instantiate your model?

Comment: Yes that is correct and sorry about that. I'm still pretty new to this site

Comment: Could you show your JQuery code then?

Comment: I just edited my original question with the jquery code. Cool dbz profile pic btw

Comment: please edit your question so it contains all information and remove the then pointless "answer". it's strangely off putting when part of the question information is posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood well your question. You can also call  your method with like this

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult getNewPrice(EasyInfoModels model, string dropdownValue, string dropdownName )
{
    // do something with value and return a decimal
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownName ))
     {
       //do something
       return Json(result)
     }
   else
    return Json("Blank");
}
```

and for your Ajax call

```
var datas = {
       fullName :$("#fullname").val(),//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       email:"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       phone :"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       topic:"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       subject:"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       paperType:"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       urgency :"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       numOfPages :"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       requirements :"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       style:"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       spacing :"",//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       price :'',//retrieve the value from your model in the view
       dropdownValue:value, 
       dropdownName: "paperType"          
    };
  $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getNewPrice","Home")',
        type:"POST",
        data:datas ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you. The `Binder` will take each value to create your model.

Comment: I guess I didn't state my question very well. I'm trying to pass the model class as a parameter from the original code that is calling the method. It is a jquery script that calls that method everytime a value in a dropdownlist gets changed

Comment: I don't understand how that code helps me access the model from within the method?